# Regex to match all sequences of words

Tags: python, regex

I need a python regex that will match all (non-empty) sequences of words in a string, assuming word is an arbitrary non-empty sequence of non-whitespace characters.

Something that will work like this:

```
s = "ab cd efg"
re.findall(..., s)
# ['ab', 'cd', 'efg', 'ab cd', 'cd efg', 'ab cd efg']
```

Closest I got to this was using `regex` module, but still **not** what I want:

```
regex.findall(r"\b\S.+\b", s, overlapped=True)
# ['ab cd efg', 'cd efg', 'efg']
```

Also, just to be clear, I **don't** want to have `'ab efg'` in there.

Comment: Since regular expressions are greedy, you can't match `'ab cd'` because any repeating regex will match all the way to the end

Comment: Why doesn't `s.split()` meet your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
matches = "ab cd efg".split()
matches2 = [" ".join(matches[i:j])
            for i in range(len(matches))
            for j in range(i + 1, len(matches) + 1)]
print(matches2)
```

Outputs:

```
['ab', 'ab cd', 'ab cd efg', 'cd', 'cd efg', 'efg']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is match all of the strings and their whitespace, and then join contiguous slices together. (this is similar to Maxim's approach though I did develop this independently, but this preserves whitespace)

```python
import regex
s = "ab cd efg"
subs = regex.findall(r"\S+\s*", s)
def combos(l):
	out = []
	for i in range(len(subs)):
		for j in range(i + 1, len(subs) + 1):
			out.append("".join(subs[i:j]).strip())
	return out
print(combos(subs))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY4xDoMwDEVncgorU1JQpKobUk/RERiABGoESeQEqT09JVC1o/2ev79/x6ezt23DxTuKQGY0LxbgDrztoNdghpGzsHZpdUA1oNXtPAvi9SOvw4UXECTTZoDeLZ0LYpYly9wa94uqYdngCBDQArV2NGI2VqQ8mawDTn@IkMO1gJ@TxsNLear13lgtOFeTw9OosJwaqUIk9EJKlpGJK1nYdeYJbRTfUufLbfsA)

This first finds all `\S+\s*` which matches a word followed by any amount of whitespace, and then gets all contiguous slices, joins them, and removes the whitespace from their right.

If whitespace is always a single space, just use Maxim's approach; it's simpler and faster but doesn't preserve whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
import itertools
def n_wise(iterable, n=2):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    iterables = itertools.tee(iterable, n)
    for k, it in enumerate(iterables):
        for _ in range(k):
            next(it, None)
    return zip(*iterables)

def foo(s):
    s = s.split()
    for n in range(1, len(s)+1):
        for thing in n_wise(s, n=n):
            yield ' '.join(thing)

s = "ab cd efg hj"
result = [thing for thing in foo(s)]
print(result)

>>> 
['ab', 'cd', 'efg', 'hj', 'ab cd', 'cd efg', 'efg hj', 'ab cd efg', 'cd efg hj', 'ab cd efg hj']
>>>
```